# Is it possible to convert a divergent series by subtracting a constant?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question came to my mind after learning about the existence of the Euler Mascheroni constant. I think that if each term of the divergent series is depressed by a certain amount then maybe the series might become convergent. However, this is just my fancy and if there is solid argument that proves that this is impossible then I would greatly appreciate as I was planning to do research on this question.

Comment: If you think of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$, the way to "adjust" it to get convergence to the Euler-Mascheroni constant is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k} - \log\frac{k+1}{k} \right)$. So the "amount" we adjust each term with is not a constant, like many of the answers interpret your question.

Answer (score 12):

$(1+\frac12)+(1+\frac14)+(1+\frac18)+\cdots$ certainly diverges; but if you subtract $1$ from each term you get the convergent series $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: Does that then imply that if there is constant term being added to the nth term of the series (and makes it divergent), by subtracting it we would always get a convergent series?

Comment: @ShreyAryan: Think carefully about what your comment asks - if we start with a convergent series and add a constant to each term, making it divergent, does subtracting the constant make it converge again? Of course, the answer should be "yes"!

Answer (score 10):

Consider the series $\sum a_n$.

If the sequence $a_n$ does not converge, then regardless of what $L$ is, $a_n-L$ does not go to zero, so $\sum (a_n-L)$ still diverges.

Suppose the sequence $a_n$ converges.  Let $L$ be the limit.  Then $a_n-L$ converges to zero.  So the series $\sum (a_n-L)$ has a chance of convergence.  But the example $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ shows that even then the series **can** diverge.  And the example $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ shows that the series **can** converge.

Comment: But $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(a_k=\frac{1}{2^n}+1\right)$ diverges yet $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(a_k-1\right)$ converges. Doesn't this contradict your first statement?

Comment: @1110101001: no, because although the series diverges in the first case, the sequence $a_k$ converges to $1$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is sometimes, but only in very specific circumstances. For example, it certainly works when the series is *eventually constant*, that is there exists an N and a c such that a_n=c for all n>N. In this case, it should be clear that subtracting the constant c will result in a finite, and hence convergent, sum.

In general, subtracting a constant will do nothing to change the divergence. You can consider the following schematic idea (note that this doesn't work in general as we are not allowed to freely rearrange the terms of a divergent, or even conditionally convergent sum):

$$``\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-c)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c"$$
If your original series was divergent then both series are divergent here (provided $c\neq0$), and you get an indeterminate result (though note this does not mean a **divergent** result - only that you can't tell whats happening at a glance).

Comment: Could you please give an example of a series that becomes eventually constant and is also divergent..

Comment: Sure, how about the series $\sum a_n$ where $a_n=1$ for every $n$?

Comment: Is there condition on the nth term of the series that can tell us whether the partial sums are going to become constant?

Comment: The rule would simply need to eventually (i.e. for large enough $n$) assign each $a_n$ the same value.

Comment: I don't think we get to rearrange the order of summation in $\sum_n (a_n - c)$ when $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @dsaxton: This is a good point, thank you. I've added it to the answer (although I should have made clear that I only meant that line to be a schematic idea as it can be dangerous to let intuition like that take hold in real analysis!),

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**: Suppose $\sum_{k} a_{k}$ is a divergent series; does there exist a real number $c$ such that $\sum_{k}(a_{k} - c)$ converges?

As Luke Hamblin's and Gerald Edgar's answers note, the question boils down to a minor variant of "does a (general) infinite series converge?"

An obvious *necessary* condition is $(a_{k}) \to c$; the terms themselves must approach a finite, non-zero limit, so that the sequence of "depressed" terms $(b_{k}) = (a_{k} - c)$ approaches $0$. The answer to Question 1 is therefore: Yes, if and only if

1. $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_{k} = c$ exists, and
2. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_{k} - c)$ converges.

---

At risk of putting words in your mouth, motivated by the Euler-Mascheroni constant, one might be tempted to relax Question 1.

**Question 2**: Suppose $\sum_{k} a_{k}$ is a divergent series; does there exist a real sequence $(c_{k})$ such that $\sum_{k}(a_{k} - c_{k})$ converges?

The answer is obviously yes; take $\sum_{k} b_{k}$ to be any convergent series, and put $c_{k} = a_{k} - b_{k}$.

Comment: Or simply take $c_k = a_k$...

Comment: @Ben: Of course; that corresponds to one's _favorite_ convergent series, $\sum_{k} 0$. Here it seemed advisable to make the general statement, since the OP seems to be looking for a characterization of a property. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not always. Consider $1+2+3+4+\dotsb$; this diverges no matter what constant you subtract from the terms. That is:
$$(1-c)+(2-c)+(3-c)+(4-c)+\dotsb$$
always diverges.